Peerdb not connecting to Click house hosted on localhost (outside docker)
Was able to connect PeerDB with PostGres on localhost (outside docker). But facing issues with connecting to ClickHouse.
Not sure if PeerDB is configured only to work with hosted ClickHouse instances. Tried with both TLS and Non-TLS connections but no luck.
Any help on this will be much appreciated.

peerdb works with non-hosted clickhouse instances. In fact, our CI just runs stock clickhouse on CI:
https://github.com/PeerDB-io/peerdb/blob/60e80b822ec284224ccb87ee008a33201d42c85d/.github/workflows/flow.yml#L123
& then e2e peer setup: https://github.com/PeerDB-io/peerdb/blob/60e80b822ec284224ccb87ee008a33201d42c85d/flow/e2e/clickhouse/clickhouse.go#L67
peerdb docker-compose files include minio to serve as s3 staging, if you're running peerdb outside of that environment you'll need to configure an s3 bucket for clickhouse
It can be awkward to connect to localhost if you're running peerdb inside docker & postgres outside docker. Would have to know more about your setup to help further

thankx for the input.
So, I'm trying to benchmark CH to PG performance via PeerDB and have both PG and CH installed on localhost outside the docker env. Was able to connect to locahost PG using host.docker.internal as the host when connecting a peer for PG. But the same is not working when trying to create a peer for CH, maybe because the peerDB is currently configured to have the DB hosted on S3 bucket.
So, any inputs for connecting CH hosted on localhost? Is it possible or not?
